# jQuery - Changing function parameters based on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty new to jquery so bear with me. I’ve got two functions, one that is intended to be used on desktop and one that is used at the tablet breakpoint. They both check for the length of a particular DOM element and pass in the width as a parameter. I’ve got another function that currently calls only one of the functions but is there a way to somehow pass in one or the other based on if they are at the tablet or mobile breakpoint? You can see in the setWidth function it's using the calculateDesktop function. I could create two different functions to do this but that would seem redundant. Kind of a newb to jquery please include code samples as necessary.

```
function calculateDesktop(width) {
 var desktop= $('.header-item').length;
 return width * ($('.header-section').length - desktop);
}

function calculateTablet(width) {
 var tablet = $('.header-item.tablet-none').length;
 return width * ($('.header-section').length - tablet);
}

function setWidth() {
   $('.expand .main-section').each(function() {
   var headerClass = $(this).closest('.header-item')).filter(function(it){
   return it.match(/^width-/); });

   var width = headerClass ? headerClass[0].split('-')[1] : 75;
   $(this).css("width", calculateDesktop(width) + "%");
});
}
```

SUDO CODE (doesn't work, but something I'm looking to achieve)

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) { 
    setWidth(calculateTablet)
} else {
    //desktop goes here
    setWidth(calculateDesktop)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the function reference as you have done then invoke that function reference to get the width

```
function setWidth(fn) {
    $('.expand .main-section').each(function () {
        var headerClass = $(this).closest('.header-item').filter(function (it) {
            return it.match(/^width-/);
        });

        var width = headerClass ? headerClass[0].split('-')[1] : 75;
        $(this).css("width", fn(width) + "%");
    });
}

if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    setWidth(calculateTablet)
} else {
    //desktop goes here
    setWidth(calculateDesktop)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot you can do that with jquery. Much appreciated!

Comment: @DelmonYoung it has nothing to do with jQuery... it is a basic javascript feature